# ERROR Doing GET with http request in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, httpclient

I have to make a list of people, with their photo, first and last name. But I can't access the API data. Within the API JSON there is a link that takes me to a second API with more data.I show a sample similar to my API and my code.
How can I get the data to display in HTML?

JSON 1

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "meta": {
        "links": { "self": { "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/" } }
      }
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "0958d35rs13",
        "links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "https://0958d35rs13"
          }
        },
        "attributes": {
          "img_array": [
            "https://testPerson1.jpg",
            "https://testPerson1.pdf"
          ],
          "num_ref": 1
        }
      }
    ]
    }
```

JSON 2

````
{
    "jsonapi": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "meta": {
        "links": { "self": { "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/" } }
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "id": "0958d35rs13",
      "links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://0958d35rs13"
        }
      },
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Pepe",
        "secondName": "James"
      }
    }
}
```

INTERFACE:
````

export interface Person {
id: string,
image: string,
name: string,
secondName: string
}

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { Person } from '../interface/inmueble';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  url = "https://apipersons/

  getAllPeople() : Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.http.get<Person[]>(this.url)
    .pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res.map(res => {
          return {
            id: res.id,
          }
        })
      })
    );
  }
```

PEOPLE TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';
import { Person } from '../interface/inmueble';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people',
  templateUrl: './people.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people.component.scss']
})
export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit {

  person: Person[] = [];

  constructor( public apiService: ApiService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void{
    
    this.apiService.getAllPeople().subscribe((data: Person[]) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.person = data;
    });
  }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? is it a http error or angular error?

Comment: The getAllPeople() method of the service does not work. The error is: The type 'Observable<{ id: string; }[]>' cannot be assigned to type 'Observable<Person[]>'. Although I have previously tried other ways of doing get() and I can't get data out. It's happening to me with this API...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here (supposing you call the JSON1) :

```js
return res.map(res => {
  return {
     id: res.id,
  }
})
```

You alter the response of the API and turn it into a simple object like `{ id: string }` which doesn't match with your signature.

Remove that part and it would be fine.

```js
return this.http.get<Person[]>(this.url)
    .pipe(
      map(res => res.data)
    );
```

Also, you could remove the `.map` operator and use a `.tap` operator, and then use an Observable in your component.

Cheers.